# Does the master equation break down for negative times?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, probability, information, stochastic-processes

I'm studying stochastic dynamics and have encountered the framework of the master equation for the study of continuous time Markov processes. First, I'll state some general definitions and then say what I'm getting puzzled at.

Suppose we have a finite number N of states and continuous time. Then, define $P_{n}(t)$ to mean the probability of our system being in state n given that we are at time t.
The formalism of the master equation states that (call $P(t)$ the column vector with entries $P_{1}(t),P_{2}(t),\cdots,P_{N}(t)$)

$$
\frac{dP(t)}{dt}=W(t)P(t)
$$
Where $W$ is the so called *transition rate matrix* and we demand it has the properties
$$
\sum_{n} W_{nm}(t) = 0
$$
and $\forall i,j $ with $i\neq j$ we have $W_{i,j}\geq 0$.

Now, to illustrate my question, let's look at a very simple case: $N=2$ and

$$
 W = \begin{bmatrix}
-1/2 & 1/2 \\
1/2 &  -1/2\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

If we know $p_{1}(0)$, that is, the probability of the system being at state one when time was $0$, we have the general solution

$$
p_{1}(t) = \frac{1}{2} + (p_{1}(0) - \frac{1}{2})e^{-t}
$$

This works fine for $ t \geq 0 $, that is, we always have $0\leq p_{1}(t) \leq 1$, as expected. However, for large negative times we get
$$
 \displaystyle \lim_{t \to -\infty}p_{1}(t) = +\infty
$$
for $p_{1}(0) > \frac{1}{2}$ and $-\infty$ for $p_{1}(0) < \frac{1}{2}$. Which is of course ludicrous.

It seems to me that we should be able to compute the probabilities for $t<0$, after all, we can deduce the probabilities of where we came from given that we are in a specific current state now using something like Bayes' theorem. So what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

One can only expect time reversal to yield physically consistent results when the evolution is unitary. Continuous time Markov processes lose information about the initial states over time and cannot be reversed.

Consider an evolution that has a single fixed point. Then all initial states will eventually tend toward that one final state. To reverse time from that final state, it is impossible to know to which "initial state" the system should tend. Only if the evolution is injective with unique inputs leading to unique outputs could you ever expect negative time evolution to not fail.

Bayes theorem will not help you if your dynamics lose information.